# when i tried to calling a dialog it will show me this error setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build

Tags: flutter, dialog, alert, setstate, bloc

**This is my dialog Code**

Here is am getting an error of setstate() or MarkerneedsBuild called during the build. this overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to process of building widgets.

When I am trying to call _onAlertOtp widget it will show me this error.in the build method, i've bloc and state when my signup is successful then i have to call alert dialog. but when I am trying to do that it will show me the error. Hope you understand the question please help me.

```
  _onAlertotp(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Enter OTP'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.7,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'We have Texted and/or Emailed OTP (One Time Pin) to your registered cell phone and/ or email account. Please check and enter OTP below to activate your TUDO account.',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 30),
                        child: PinCodeTextField(
                          length: 6, // must be greater than 0
                          obsecureText: false, //optional, default is false
                          shape: PinCodeFieldShape
                              .underline, //optional, default is underline
                          onDone: (String value) {
                            setState(() {
                              passcode = value;
                              print(value);
                            });
                          },

                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight
                                  .bold), //optinal, default is TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                          onErrorCheck: (bool value) {
                            setState(() {
                              hasError = value;
                            });
                          },
                          shouldTriggerFucntions:
                              changeNotifier.stream.asBroadcastStream(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                        child: Text(
                          hasError
                              ? "*Please fill up all the cells and press VERIFY again"
                              : "",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.red.shade300, fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      RichText(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: "Didn't receive the code? ",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 15),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: " RESEND",
                                  // recognizer: onTapRecognizer,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: colorStyles["primary"],
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16))
                            ]),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 7,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 30),
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          height: 50,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              /// check the [_onData] fucntion to understand better
                              changeNotifier.add(Functions.submit);
                              // at first we will check error on the press of the button.
                              if (!hasError) {
                                _onAlertrunnigbusiness(context);
                              }
                            },
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              "VERIFY".toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )),
                          ),
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: colorStyles["primary"],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Regret'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Here Is Another DIalog. which open on first dialog verify button click

```
  _onAlertrunnigbusiness(context) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Are you running Business?'),
          content: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                    "TUDO.App aims at Businesses bridging gaps between Business Service Providers and Consumers collaborate on unique technology platform. If you own a business, we strongly recommend, provide your business information to grow your customer base and expand your business services. Any questions? Call us @1-800-888-TUDO"),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton.icon(
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowCircleRight),
                      label: Text('No'),
                      color: colorStyles["primary"],
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        NavigationHelper.navigatetoMainscreen(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    FlatButton.icon(
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowCircleRight),
                      label: Text('Yes'),
                      color: colorStyles["primary"],
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        NavigationHelper.navigatetoBspsignupcreen(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Close'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**And Here i am calling my dialog**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<SignupBloc, SignupState>(
      bloc: widget._signupBloc,
      listener: (
        BuildContext context,
        SignupState currentState,
      ) {


        if (currentState is InSignupState) {
          _countries = currentState.countries.countries;
          return Container(child: content(_signupBloc, context, _countries));
        }

        if (currentState is SignupButtonClickedEvent) {
          print('SignupButtonClickedEvent clicked');
          return Container();
        }

        if (currentState is SignupSuccessState) {
          print(
              ' You are awesome. you have successfully registered without confirmation');
          print(currentState.signupUser.toJson());
          print("Hey Otp Is opned");

          if (!_isError) {
            return _onAlertotp(context);
          }
          // NavigationHelper.navigatetoMainscreen(context);
          _isLoading = false;
          showAlertBox = true;
          return Container(
            child: content(_signupBloc, context, _countries),
          );
        }

        if (currentState is SignupVerficationOtp) {
          print('signup verficitaion otp button clicked');
          return Container();
        }
        return Container(child: content(_signupBloc, context, _countries));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using below code to display an alert dialog

in place of return _onAlertotp(context);

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // show alert dialog here
  _onAlertotp(context);
});
```

Comment: You are awesome Man!! It's working fine :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: I've did but after open dialog in the dialog there one button when I am click on that button it will open another dialog. but right now when I I am click on first dialog button it will open second dialog and suddenly get back to the first dialog

Comment: but there is only one dialog in your question, where is another dialog

Comment: I've updated question. i've posted another dialog please check it out

Comment: When i am click on verify it will have to first check all 6 digit is filed or not if filled then it will redirect to second dialog. Hope you understand.

Comment: try removing  /// check the [_onData] fucntion to understand better
                              changeNotifier.add(Functions.submit);

and check

Comment: But dialog open everywhere when i am redirected to next page from the dialog at that page i am also getting dialog opened

Comment: okay we'll check about this and let you know if found any solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199514/discussion-between-rutvik-gumasana-and-kailash-chouhan).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a BlocListener at the root of your build method to handle events that do not return a widget (in your case the showDialog method)

Your `if (currentState is SignupSuccessState) {` part would be in the BlocListener and not in the BlocBuilder

Comment: i've tried but it showing me the blank page. Can you please help me to code this. Hope you Understand please help me.

Comment: Please update the question and code with the BlocListener, it is hard to know what could be happening without it.

Comment: You should combine both BlocListener and BlocBuilder. BlocBuilder for the places where you build Widgets and BlocListener for the places where you do side effects (show a dialog for instance)

Comment: Can you please help me the example code so i can implement it